# Constructor with multiple type arguments list in java grammar

Tags: java, grammar, specifications, jls

The [java grammar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html) from the Java Language Specification v7 specifies the following grammar rules for constructors:

```
Primary:
    ...
    new Creator
    ...

Creator:  
    NonWildcardTypeArguments CreatedName ClassCreatorRest
    CreatedName ( ClassCreatorRest | ArrayCreatorRest )

CreatedName:   
    Identifier [TypeArgumentsOrDiamond] { . Identifier [TypeArgumentsOrDiamond] }

ClassCreatorRest: 
    Arguments [ClassBody]
```

What puzzles me here is the `CreatedName` rule. By that token, expressions such as

```
new Class1<Integer>.Class2<Integer>();
```

would be valid constructors. Which they of course aren't.

In fact, I can't find any case were a chain of identifier (e.g. `Class1.Class2`) would have more than one type parameter list (e.g. `<Integer>`). Do such cases exist, or does the grammar makes no sense?

For reference, the equivalent grammar rules given in the [section 15.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9) of the JLS exhibit the same problem (those rules reference the `TypeDecl` non-terminal, which is defined in [section 4.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule looks like a trick to allow both in a single rule:

- `new Class1<...>();`
- `new Class1.Class2<...>(); // Where Class2 is a static inner class`

The allowed expression: `new Class1<Integer>.Class2<Integer>();` will never compile in Java since:

> The member type Class1.Class2 cannot be qualified with a
>   parameterized type, since it is static. Remove arguments from
>   qualifying type Class1

Comment: Why not express the rule as a qualified identifier (Class1.Class2) followed by a an optional type parameter list then? This would seems like the obvious thing to do.

Comment: What about this: `Identifier [TypeArgumentsOrDiamond] | Identifier.Identifier[TypeArgumentsOrDiamond]` ?

Comment: I don't really understand your answer: I asked why was Java doing it like it is and not like `Identifier (.Identifier)* TypeArgumentsOrDiamond?`.

Answer (score 1):

The grammar just describes a super set of valid Java source code. As far as I know, only the last `TypeArgumentsOrDiamond` may exist, but the (simplified) grammar you are looking at does not deal with this corner case.